# Do I have a proper understanding of how this code works?

Tags: ruby

Basically, I'm trying to solve the very first Project Euler problem with Ruby. [Here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) is the problem if you want to know for reference. I tried doing the problem myself from scratch, but that wasn't going over quite so well, so I decided to go another route: find someone else's solution online, crack it apart, explain it to myself and try to see if I could build my own unique solution if I could figure out exactly what their code was doing. In my experience, this is just always the best way for me to learn. Here's the solution I found and decided to rip apart:

```
puts (1..1000).select{ |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }.reduce(:+)
```

I found this solution [here](https://gist.github.com/nefarioustim/1008926). Basically, what I want is less "tell me the answer to the problem" and more "read my notes and tell me what's right, what's wrong, and break down the problem step by step for me." Again, if this isn't a proper use of SO, I'm so sorry! I wasn't sure where else to ask and I will delete my question if this isn't where I should be asking. :) Here's my notes on the code and how I explained it to myself:

> - it puts numbers 1-999 ("range") down
> - then selects it with ".select". the curly brackets are used almost like css, but are more similar to "do" and "end" in Ruby ("do" starting a command and "end" ending it). The difference between "do/end" and curly brackets are that curly brackets are for commands that can fit into one line rather than needing several lines.
> - | | = the pipelines define a "block" whereas "n" stands for numeral/number. it's a block with a variable inside of it. this means that |n| asks the command to bring up a number from the selected range.
> - "n % 3" looks for multiples of 3; == 0 looks for the answer(?). repeat for five.
> - then ".reduce(:+)" shortens the command by summing all of the numerals together.

I feel a little confident in my understanding of it, but if anything is off (terminology, general concept, etc), I'd love if you'd let me know and explain it! I'm really just trying to learn and taking things apart and explaining them to myself usually helps me the most.

Comment: that's exactly what's happening here. you understand it correctly, i couldn't explain it better myself. just addition to your explanation, `.select` is like a filter function, it filters the array of the range, and what's inside is the condition `n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0` which is to choose all the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5. My suggestion is that as a beginner, try to write most of the code in block format to get a better understanding how they work before you shorten everything to one line.

Comment: `..` run from the beginning to the end *inclusively*. `...` *exclude* the end value.

Comment: Both those things help! Thank you!

Comment: It puts numbers 1-1000 and looks for any number that is dividable by 3 or 5 and sums those numbers together

Answer (score 1):

**In plain english the statement prints the result of taking every number between 1 and 1000 which is divisible by 3 or 5 and returns the sum of the set (234168).**

`puts` just a simple print command which writes to the output buffer (STDio by default). `puts` adds a newline after each argument. `print` does not.

> [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)
>   Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which the given
>   block returns a true value.

So yes in this case it will allow any value which is divisible by 3 or 5

```
irb(main):005:0> (1..10).select{ |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }
=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

> the curly brackets are used almost like css, but are more similar to
>   "do" and "end" in Ruby

I'm not so sure about the likeness to CSS since CSS is just a declarative language.

Both curly brackets and `do ... end` are Rubys way of declaring blocks - which are just anonymous functions. The compiler does not actually care and will let you write multi-line statements with brackets. However there is a strong community convention that `do ... end` should be preferred for longer statements.

In Javascript with the Underscore library it would look like this:

```
console.log( 
  _.filter( 
    _.range(1, 10), function(n){ n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 } 
  )
);
```

> [`reduce(sym) → obj`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
>
> Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation,
>   specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.

So reduce takes the array we get as a result from select and adds the elements together. `:+` is actually the method we call on the 'memo'.

```
[1,2,3].reduce(:+)
```

Can also be written as:

```
[1,2,3].reduce { |memo, obj| memo.send(:+, obj) }
# or
[1,2,3].reduce { |memo, obj| memo.+(obj) }
```

This might look kind of strange but just remember that in Ruby everything is an object. `+` is actually a method on the [`FixNum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html) class and not a keyword like in other languages.

So `1 + 2` in Ruby actually syntactic sugar for `1.+(2)`.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, when to use `do...end` vs when to use curly brackets is purely for human understanding, and not so much the computer? So my code won't break if I used curly brackets for multiple lines, it just may not look as "pretty". Then reduce gathers everything select picked out and, with the memo `:+` in mind, sums it all up, right?

Comment: @SarahAnne: that's correct. `[1, 2, 3].reduce(:+)` is equivalent to `1 + 2 + 3`

Comment: To be 100% correct `[1,2,3].reduce(&:+)` is the same as your examples. `[1,2,3].reduce(:+)` is special case for symbol (faster one).

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> it puts numbers 1-999 ("range") down

I'm not sure what *"puts numbers down"* is supposed to mean.

[`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) writes the given objects (i.e. its arguments) to the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) which is your terminal by default. In your example, it outputs the *result* of the given expression. But to do so, the expression has to be evaluated.

`1..1000` creates a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html), an object representing the interval from `1` to `1000` inclusively. The range is wrapped in parentheses, because `1..1000.select` would attempt to call `1000.select` which results in an error. `(1..1000).select` works as expected.

> then selects it with ".select".

[`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) is a method coming from [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) – a module that provides functionality to collections like `Array`, `Hash` or `Range`. `select` doesn't "select the range", it selects elements from the range based on a condition. Think of it as a filter.

> the curly brackets are used almost like css ...

Well, `{ ... }` are called "blocks", both in CSS and in Ruby.

But in CSS, these blocks are used to group multiple declarations that apply to a selector.

In Ruby, a block argument sends a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) to the method. So instead of passing a static value to `select`, you pass a function. `select` can call this function (i.e. the block) later on.

> ... but are more similar to "do" and "end" in Ruby

For blocks, you can use `do ... end` instead of `{ ... }` and vice versa but you might have to add parentheses or a semicolon to achieve the same result.

> ("do" starting a command and "end" ending it)

*block*, not command.

> The difference between "do/end" and curly brackets are that curly brackets are for commands that can fit into one line rather than needing several lines.

That's a convention (there are [other conventions](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2011/07/26/the-procedurefunction-block-convention-in-ruby/), too). The actual difference is precedence, see the examples for [block arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument).

> | | = the pipelines define a "block" whereas "n" stands for numeral/number. it's a block with a variable inside of it.

`{ ... }` defines a block. `| ... |` holds the arguments that are passed to the block. `n` is such an argument. The number of arguments is specified by the method calling the block (`select` in this case), but you can choose the argument's name.

> this means that |n| asks the command to bring up a number from the selected range.

The block is passive, it doesn't ask for anything. And there is no "selected range". `select` is a method. It passes each number from the range to the given block. Within the block, this number can be referenced via `n`.

Even `select` doesn't know the elements, it has to call [`Range#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html#method-i-each) in order to iterate over the collection.

> "n % 3" looks for multiples of 3;

`n % 3` returns the *modulo*, i.e. the remainder of dividing *n* by 3:

```
1 % 3 #=> 1     1 divided by 3 = 0, remainder 1
2 % 3 #=> 2     2 divided by 3 = 0, remainder 2
3 % 3 #=> 0     3 divided by 3 = 1, remainder 0
4 % 3 #=> 1     4 divided by 3 = 1, remainder 1
```

> == 0 looks for the answer(?)

It compares the result of `n % 3` with `0`. In other words, `n % 3 == 0` returns `true` if `n` is divisible by `3` and `false` otherwise.

> repeat for five.

There's also a `||` in between which is a logical *OR*.

`n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0` translates to *"n is divisible by 3 OR n is divisible by 5"*.

> then ".reduce(:+)" shortens the command by summing all of the numerals together.

First of all, `select` returns a new array. More explicitly, `select` returns a new array containing all elements from `1..1000` for which the block returns `true`.

[`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) then applies the operation denoted by `:+` to all these elements.

`[1, 2, 3].reduce(:+)` is equivalent to `1 + 2 + 3`

Answer (score 0):

{} curly bracket has higher precedence than *do..end.*

You can use {} for multiple line, too. But *do..end* can not be written in a single line.

for .select, it returns a new array.

```
>array = []
>array = (1..1000).select{ |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }
>array
```

will return the array with number those can be divided by 3 or 5 between 1 to 1000.

Comment: So curly brackets are more flexible than `do...end`, basically. And .select picks things from the first array, bunches them together and gives me a new array with those numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be super-explicit about this bit from your answer:

> "n % 3" looks for multiples of 3; == 0 looks for the answer(?). repeat
>   for five.

It doesn't "repeat" for 5. Here, this symbol "||" represents "logical OR." What this means is that this line:

```
{ |n| n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 }
```

looks for all numbers n such that n is a multiple of 3 OR n is a multiple of 5.

You can get a nice understanding of Ruby logical operators here:

[Ruby the Hard Way ex 27](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex27.html)